# Display the data in spgridview with several column in each row

Tags: development, asp.net, spgridview

I need to develop a webpart which takes data from list and populate in spgridview.
The webpart should look like in the image atached.
I am able to display the column 1  i.e one image for each row but 
How do I create the column 2 , which have several rows to be displayed from the list?

[image]

Comment: I love the artist's rendering of a SPGridView. :)

Comment: Need some details..
The Column 2 contains how many rows? and those rows are from the same list? any conditions or grouping needed?

Comment: no conditional grouping needed . column 2 contains 3 rows and inside each row there is need of 4-5 row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by Grid view template field property .
Created a table with my required structure and attached it with template field

Check this link for other option which is helpful : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a577f3/5120/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are using as the DataSource for your SPGridView but lets assume a `DataTable` object.

I would just generate the HTML you need (list?) and update the rows in the DataTable.

Then, I would use a regular 'ole [BoundField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.aspx) with [HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.htmlencode.aspx) set to `false` so that the HTML displays in the SPGridView column.

Comment: the sp list is datasource and i m using data table .any link would be appreciated